# Magento block rewrite not working properly

Tags: magento

I am trying to rewrite product_new block. Purpose is that i want to add category_id field and fetch new products of one category only. Here is the code

app\code\local\Foo\Bar\Block\Product\New.php

class Foo_Bar_Block_Product_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
{

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
  //  echo "aaaaaaasdfa";

    $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1)
    ;

  if($categoryId=$this->getData('category_id')){
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
  }


    $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

}

Added block in local.xml using below code

```
        <block type="foo_bar/product_new" name="new_products_list" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
            <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>4</category_id></action>
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>

        </block>
```

module's config.xml is

```
<global>
<blocks>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
    <product_new>Foo_Bar_Block_Product_New</product_new>
        </rewrite>
</catalog>
</blocks>
</global>
```

Please guide me where I am making mistake

Thanks

Comment: There are new products in catalog for mentioned category_id. Currently the result is an empty block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is on parent::_beforeToHtml(); statement it will call _beforeToHtml method of parent class which is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New. So parent function will override collection which you have set.

Solution:

Replace :

```
parent::_beforeToHtml();
```

to :

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::_beforeToHtml();
```

Comment: I still see blank block. Nothing in it. Please check names and block calling in local.xml are they okay? Please advise

Comment: I just saw in log. I get this
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Foo_Bar_Block_Product_New'

Comment: Thanks for the help. code is working fine now. After doing your said change i just changed <block type="foo_bar/product_new" to <block type="catalog/product_new" .